# IIS Express Asp.Net long URL returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-express

**Update:**

The stack trace was due to a proxy where the correct Web.Config was not altered. However creating a new project -> ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) using .NET Framework 4.6.1 the exact same bad request error is present. Even after updating `Web.config` with the following values:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None"/>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxUrlLength="2048" maxQueryStringLength="32768" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
...
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" maxAllowedContentLength="32768" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

**Original:**

I'm having a weird problem.

The following URL with 203 characters works:

https://localhost:44369/api/Account/testReset/AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE12fCl12bsBAAAA9B6VBWG0rESm48zX3kvFAgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABrejIuYGBxLG912bGeknd3Iww12b9dhdzE99tfhdGW1FPbmQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAAWg

The following URL with 303 characters gives a stack trace error:

https://localhost:44369/api/Account/testReset/AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE12fCl12bsBAAAA9B6VBWG0rESm48zX3kvFAgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABrejIuYGBxLG912bGeknd3Iww12b9dhdzE99tfhdGW1FPbmQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAAWgI6mOVdROCbpPBF71QQsivA1VaIPJuALkCN4A5kFUEAAAAAa905JtNQkjp1KFUZJks6PuShgpYDv4nQvTAJTYnzxJu5BvT3AdB12b

> The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured
>   maxUrlLength value.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The length of the URL
>   for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The length of the URL for this request
>   exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9939787
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

[image]

This URL with 403 characters gives me 400 Bad Request page:

https://localhost:44369/api/Account/testReset/AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE12fCl12bsBAAAA9B6VBWG0rESm48zX3kvFAgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAABrejIuYGBxLG912bGeknd3Iww12b9dhdzE99tfhdGW1FPbmQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAAWgI6mOVdROCbpPBF71QQsivA1VaIPJuALkCN4A5kFUEAAAAAa905JtNQkjp1KFUZJks6PuShgpYDv4nQvTAJTYnzxJu5BvT3AdB12bIobF0DrIjWDgzrTa7ddaOLWfekVuEvEZJQAAAAN9tYCLKXD6Z1BembCCgBa7XkUhs0aOsLj0euwKYaR12b799hD812bO1pMsKXwl

[image]

The question is two parts: Why do I receive different errors and what can I do to fix it? I know I can send the request with `?token=` with route `[Route("testReset")]` to get it to work but this is about setting the URL length.

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("testReset/{token}")]
public IHttpActionResult Test(string token)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxUrlLength="2048" maxQueryStringLength="32768" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

From this thread:

[How do I increase the maxUrlLength property in the config in asp.net MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245843/how-do-i-increase-the-maxurllength-property-in-the-config-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: Check if you modified the correct `web.config` file, as the source code won't lie, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,2618

Comment: @LexLi Updated the question. Indeed the stack trace was due to this but the Bad Request is still there.

Answer (score 1):

On Web.config under system webserver tag u have to add this :

```
 <security>
<requestFiltering>
  <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
</requestFiltering>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason of the same problem was default value of UrlSegmentMaxLength=260
(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/httpsys-registry-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.` when I tried to make like your `[Route("testReset/{token}")]`

I just removed "/{token}" from the Route, I used "[FromQuery]" on token parameter and I invoked it using the url like "https://localhost:44357/testReset?token=[[replace_by_your_token_value_here]]"

Example:

**Step 1:**
`[Route("testReset")]`
`public IHttpActionResult Test([FromQuery] string token)`

**Step 2:**
And calling by url (I adapted the url with your parameters):
`https://localhost:44357/testReset?token={tokenValue}`

Worked for me without change maxAllowedContentLengthor or any changes in web.config